# Use default menu icons for an Action

Tags: menu, action, toolbar, menuitem, netbeans-platform

I have a question about the use of the Menu/Toolbar icons:

I have a Netbeans Platform application with one Menu; in this Menu i have added some items they represents the Actions.

Now, i've a "SaveAction" and i want associate it to the default MenuItem "Save" given by Netbeans Platform, for using the same icons.

Same thing for the Toolbar.

How can i do this?